# Compilar varios archivos juntos en vscode?

Tags: c++

Como trabajar con archivos .h y .cpp, no se como enlazarlos

este es el arbol:

```
header
   alphabet.h
source
  alphabet.cpp
  main.cpp
```

** Estoy usando visual studio.**

este es mi git donde esta el proyecto: https://github.com/hubmanS/c-Demo

alphabet.h

```
int add(int , int ); // function prototype for add.h -- don't forget the semicolon!
```

alphabet.cpp

```
#include "../header/alphabet.h"

int add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

y el main

```
#include <iostream>
#include "../header/alphabet.h" // Insert contents of add.h at this point.  Note use of double quotes here.

int main()
{
    std::cout << "The sum of 3 and 4 is " << add(3, 4) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

**obtengo este error: undefined reference to `add(int, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1**

con este task.json estoy compilando y ejecutando:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "debug",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "",
            "args": ["g++","-g", "${relativeFile}", "-o","a.exe"]
        },
        {
            "label": "Compile and run",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "",
            "args": [
                "g++","-g", "${relativeFile}", "-o","${fileBasenameNoExtension}.out", "&&", "clear" , "&&" , "./${fileBasenameNoExtension}.out"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true  
            },
            "problemMatcher": {
                "owner": "cpp",
                "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceRoot}"],
                "pattern": {
                    "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                    "file": 1,
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 3,
                    "severity": 4,
                    "message": 5
                }
            }
        },

    ]
}
```

Comment: Descarge tu proyecto y lo probé usando Visual C++ 2008, a mi me funciona, asi que el problema no está  en el código... pero por lo que veo en tu error parece ser un error de linkeo ¿Estas en linux? ¿Enlazar por consola? quizas estás enlazando sólo el "main.o" y te estaría faltando el "alphabet.o"

Comment: @GermánMartínez si estoy en linux

Comment: @GermánMartínez Executing task:  g++ -g automata/source/main.cpp -o main.out && clear && ./main.out <

/tmp/ccHdhAVd.o: In function `main':
/home/ubuntu/Escritorio/competitive/compile/automata/source/main.cpp:6: undefined reference to `add(int, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

Comment: @GermánMartínez ese es el mensaje de error que obtengo

Comment: Por lo que veo, sólo estas compilando el main.cpp, te falta el alphabet.cpp

Comment: @GermánMartínez como puedo agregarlo en el task?

Comment: Eso del task nunca lo usé, pero con el g++, sería algo así: `g++ -g {ruta del main}/main.cpp {ruta del alphabet}/alphabet.cpp`

Comment: @GermánMartínez pero si ahora el problema es con un archivo, en el futuro tendre que poner varios archivos para compilar ? g++ -g main.cpp file.cpp file2.cpp ...................fileN.cpp

Comment: Si, con muchos archivos tendría que ser: `g++ -g main.cpp file.cpp file2.cpp ...................fileN.cpp`, es que todos los archivos de códico tienen que ser compilados y para poder ser enlazados.

Comment: Sobre esa herramienta task, si automatiza mas las cosas no lo sé, pero de la manera tradicional usando g++, hay que compilar cada archivo pasandolos por parametros, o llamar N veces a g++ para cada uno de los archivos y enlazarlos posteriormente.

Answer (score 1):

Tuve el mismo problema que tú. Lo ideal es que en cada proyecto vayas actualizando el archivo `tasks.json` (que está en la carpeta `.vscode`) con los archivos que añadas, ya que hasta donde yo he investigado no hay forma de automatizarlo :(.

La diferencia al usar un IDE de verdad como Visual Studio o Code::Blocks es que estos, cuando añades un archivo al proyecto, lo añaden también a la tarea de compilar. Aún así, personalmente, prefiero Visual Code.

¡Suerte con tus proyectos!